# Extract only text files from a zip file

Tags: command-line

I have a zip file newfile.zip.

```
Archive:  newfile.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  2019-11-22 02:00   newdir/
       33  2019-11-22 01:31   newdir/file1.txt
        0  2019-11-22 01:31   newdir/dir1/
       79  2019-11-22 01:45   newdir/dir1/file11.txt
       35  2019-11-22 01:43   newdir/file100.txt
        0  2019-11-22 02:00   newdir/file1
        0  2019-11-22 02:00   newdir/file2
---------                     -------
      147                     7 files
```

I want to extract the files with the extension .txt.
I use this command,

```
$ unzip newfile.zip newdir/*.txt
```

This command extract the files,

```
newdir/file100.txt
newdir/file1.txt
```

but not the file, `newdir/dir1/file11.txt`

So how to extract it?

Comment: try `unzip newfile.zip *.txt` it works for me

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. `unzip newdir.zip newdir/*.txt` for me also unzips the *.txt. file in the subfolder dir1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have these folders and files:

```
.
├── a
│   └── file1a.txt
├── b
│   ├── file1b.txt
│   └── file2b.txt
├── c
│   ├── file1c.txt
│   └── file2c.txt
├── emptydoc
└── file2.txt
```

I got all of them compressed to `compressed.zip`.
If I want to unzip text files only, I run this command `unzip compressed.zip *.txt` and I only get the `.txt` files unzipped

```
unzip compressed.zip *.txt
Archive:  compressed.zip
  inflating: a/file1a.txt            
  inflating: b/file1b.txt            
  inflating: b/file2b.txt            
  inflating: c/file1c.txt            
  inflating: c/file2c.txt            
  inflating: file2.txt
```